# Unable to send or retrive data in the Firebase Web

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am facing a problem in sending or retrieving the data from the Firebase web.

Although I can successfully register the user and I can even get the user UID by writing the code shown below-

```
if(user!=null)
{

    var uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    console.log(`UID ===> ${uid}`)

}
```

But still I cannot retrieve/send data from/to the Firebase. **I am not even getting any error in the console.**

My codes for index.js file in the functions folder is below-

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
var admin = require('firebase-admin');


var serviceAccount = require('/path/to/my/serviceAccount/key.json');

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: 'https://urlOfMyDatabaseURL.firebaseio.com'
});


const app = express();
app.get('/', (request, response)=>{

     response.send(index.html);

});


exports.app=functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Please help, I am stuck here!